# Can I use Vue.compile to compile an HTML snippet?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to be able to use `Vue.compile` same as one uses [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/). For context, this is so I can then use the HTML snippet as a [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) popup - over a few hundred items.

So I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
var popup = '<div><b><a href="#">{{ m.itemLabel }}</a></b><br />{{ m.architectLabel }}</div>';

var m = {
         "architectLabel":"Luigi Lorenzo Secchi",
         "itemLabel":"Leonardo Da Vinci school",
         "location":{"lat":"45.47735","lng":"9.22452"}
       };

var res = Vue.compile(popup)
console.log('res', res.render(m));
```

but this results in an error:

```
ReferenceError: _c is not defined
```

Is this possible at all? or is this a bad idea and there is a more vue.js-like way to approach this?